# Javadoc task in Ant build fails

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

I'm receiving an error message from Ant  when I try to run the Javadoc ant task.

"BUILD FAILED
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/LearnJava/Observer/build.xml:39: No source files, no packages and no modules have been specified."

The build files reside at:

https://github.com/Fernal73/LearnJava/blob/master/Observer/build.properties

```
version=1.0.0
main.class=com.javacodegeeks.patterns.observerpattern.TestObserver
main.class1=com.javacodegeeks.patterns.observerpattern.Test
cs.properties=../checkstyle.properties
gformat.properties=../gformat.properties
ant.build.javac.source=1.7
ant.build.javac.target=1.7
packages=com.javacodegeeks.patterns.observerpatern.*
```

and
https://github.com/Fernal73/LearnJava/blob/master/Observer/build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Observer" default="main"
  basedir=".">
  <property file = "build.properties"/>
  <property file = "${cs.properties}"/>
  <property file = "${gformat.properties}"/>
    <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
    <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
    <property name="src.dir" location="." />
    <property name="build.dir" location="." />
    <property name="dist.dir" location="dist" />
    <property name="docs.dir" location="docs" />
    <taskdef resource="${cs.taskdef.resource}"
      classpath="../${cs.jar}"/>
    <!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="." includes="**/*.class"/>
    </delete>       
        <delete dir="${docs.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
    </target>
    <!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
    <target name="makedir">
        <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
    </target>
    <!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
    <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir,gformat,checkstyle">
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
<compilerarg value="-Xlint:-options"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <!-- Creates Javadoc -->
    <target name="docs" depends="compile">
      <javadoc  packagenames="${packages}" additionalparam="-Xdoclint:none" 
        sourcepath="${src.dir}" 
        destdir="${docs.dir}">
            <!-- Define which files / directory should get included, we include all -->
             <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="*.java" />
             </fileset>
        </javadoc>
      </target>
      <target name="manifest">
        <tstamp/>
      <manifest file="manifest.mf">
  <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
<section name="common">
    <attribute name="Specification-Title" value="${ant.project.name}"/>
    <attribute name="Specification-Version" value="${version}"/>
    <attribute name="Specification-Vendor" value=""/>
    <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value=""/>
    <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${build} ${TODAY}"/>
    <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value=""/>
  </section>
  <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}" />
</manifest>
</target>
    <!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
    <target name="jar" depends="compile,manifest">
      <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${build.dir}" includes="**/*.class"
        manifest="manifest.mf">
</jar>
</target>
<target name="run" >
<description>Run target</description>
<java classname="${main.class}">
 <classpath>
   <pathelement location="${dist.dir}\${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
<pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
</classpath>
</java>
</target>
<target name="gformat">
  <exec executable="find" dir="${basedir}"
    failonerror="true" outputproperty="sources"> 
            <arg line=" . -type f -name '*.java'"/>  
          </exec>
          <echo message="About to format ...: ${sources}"/>
          <java classname="${gformat.main.class}">
            <arg line=" -i ${sources}"/>
 <classpath>
   <pathelement location="../${gformat.jar}"/>
<pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
</classpath>
</java>
    </target>
<target name="checkstyle">
  <first id="checkstylefile">
    <fileset dir=".." includes="${cs.config}"/>
  </first>
  <checkstyle config="${toString:checkstylefile}"
    classpath="../${cs.jar}"
    failOnViolation="false" properties="${cs.properties}">
  <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.java"/>
  <formatter type="plain"/>
  <formatter type="plain" toFile="${cs.output}"/>
</checkstyle>
</target>
<target name="main" depends="compile, jar, docs">
        <description>Main target</description>
    </target>
</project>
```

respectively.

My other projects on the repository have similar configurations.

They work as expected.

Am I missing something obvious?

***I did miss something obvious. An extra 't' in the property packages. Evidently, I'm going to need two sets of eyes for this or a fresh set, a few hours later!***

NOW, how do I close this?

Comment: Include your build files in your question itself, as code-formatted blocks.  External links can become stale over time (for instance, if your project were moved or deleted), which would make your question useless to future readers.  Also, please include the entire text of the error message you’re seeing.

Comment: Thanks. I've included the file contents in the post. I had a problem earlier ; Stackoverflow kept asking for four space indentations. The error is specific to the Observer project. No errors with the other projects in the repository. You're right about stale links; I could have discovered a fix since!

Comment: “Am I missing something obvious?” You’re; it’s 2019, and no one should be using Ant.

Comment: Ah! That's fine. According to you, nobody should be using scripts either. I started this on Termux which has no access to a Java environment except for Dalvikvm. I then moved to Arch Linux on Termux but wished to retain the existing directory structure. Ant was and is more configurable. Maven and/or Gradle will have to wait. This is all via the command line, by the way. No Eclipse or any other IDEs. Do check out my other queries if you don't believe me.

Comment: Don’t listen to Abhijit.  Ant is by far the best build tool for Java.  (Oh, and Maven and Gradle use Ant under the hood.)

Comment: https://www.theserverside.com/feature/Why-we-still-use-Apache-Ant-tool-in-Java-build-and-deploys

Comment: That's fine. I'll have to explore Maven and Gradle at some point as well. For now, my projects are quite small. Complexity is minimum and dependency Management is not needed.

Comment: What I like about Ant is that I can configure it to reproduce what I do with my shell scripts. If not, I can run the shell scripts from within Ant. I'm unaware how easy it is to do this from Maven.

Comment: At some point, I'll have to look at Ivy for dependency Management. I have a couple of jars in my repository that make cloning quite a pain. Thanks.

Comment: I just had a quick dekko at Ivy. I evidently don't need it in my projects, as yet. If I'd like to manage dependencies, it's for Checkstyle and Google Java Formatter and possibly Walkmod, which I haven't integrated as yet. The documentation for Walkmod is sparse, to say the least. With Ivy, I tried it but it downloads all these jars and artifacts I don't need. What's the best way to specify that dependencies are not to be downloaded and only executable jars or the default artifact is to be downloaded? I can't find any relevant examples for the same. Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: I can understand if the additional jars are dependencies but javadocs and sources are downloaded too.

Comment: Additionally, I'm assuming these transitive dependencies as defined in the remote default configuration would be the same as the jars included in the all or all-deps jars that Google java format and checkstyle provide. Since these are being provided by these open source projects, why aren't they simply made available via Maven? Is there a different remote configuration other than default or master that I should be aware of? Yes, a path could be built to these transitive dependencies using the resolve Ivy task, but if there's an all dependencies jar available, why would I care?

Comment: Also, this leaves the Onus of bundling jars needed for an executable jar on the developer, from these transitive dependencies, that is.

Comment: I finally went with Ivy and included build files that resolve dependencies and that path is passed to Checkstyle and Google Java Format in the including builds. You can check out my root folder's build and ivy files and the Hello project for an including build project. I wanted to stick with creating an all-encompassing jar but that takes an inordinate amount of time to create.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in following part:

```
<fileset dir="${src.dir}">
    <include name="*.java" />
</fileset>
```

In Ant "`*.java`" means all files with names matching *.java. This does not search in subdirectories.
To include all subdirectories you must specify:

```
<fileset dir="${src.dir}">
    <include name="**/*.java" />
</fileset>
```

But since you already specified the `sourcePath` attribute I'm wondering if you can't just remove the fileset element as ant will add **/*.java by default.

Comment: @VGR as I suggested at the end. thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Oops, sorry, my oversight.

Comment: @Conffusion Thanks. REMOVED the Javadoc cruft. Took me some time to come around to it.